# How to pass Javascript api request result variables to shopify liquid variable

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a javascript that makes a api call and gets a json response.
I need to pass this to my liquid template and iterate over it.

How do i pass the result variable on get request to a shopify liquid variable.?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Liquid is rendered Server Side... whereas your Javascript is considered to be client side coding. When you are rendering your Liquid, you can transfer Liquid into Javascript for use later, but not vice versa.

Also, if you are getting JSON via an API call and you need to iterate over it, why are you not just using Javascript. You do not need Liquid to iterate over data.

Comment: @DavidLazar because JS-rendered apps are not SEO friendly and most Shopify sites are written in Liquid.

Comment: @DavidLazar You literally asked why you are not using just JavaScript. And you suggested to not use Liquid when OP uses Liquid. It's very hard to just switch.