# Shopify (liquid) Count size of options in select and change style

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I have a selection of options by images: http://www.raues.com/products/copy-of-black-and-blue-glasses-top

I want to count the number of images in each option and change the style (width) of the images according to that number. I found this code that can count the size of the select input:

> document.querySelector("#{{settings.option1_title}}").length;

So I did the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
               var len = document.querySelector("#{{settings.option1_title}}").length;

{% if len < 10) %}

<style>
ul.thumbnails.image_picker_selector li {
  max-width: 160px; }
</style>

{% endif %}               

</script>
```

But it does not work. I think liquid does not read the "len" variable that I created before and I am not sure if it is the proper way to add the style to the code if statement is true.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Liquid is rendered first server-side, whereas javascript is run client-side ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25750762/1367622)).

Therefore your javascript `len` variable does not exist at the time the liquid if statement `{% if len < 10 %}` is evaluated. Use a javascript if statement here instead.